# Azure Web App for Containers - How Auto Scale handles internal server storage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've some doubts about autoscaling and Azure Web App for Containers.

We currently have the "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE" option = true, so, our containers are accessing the web server to store files, great!

But, in an autoscaling moment, how this storage will be handled? The apps will have access to these files, have I/O and when it scales down, all files will be "merged"?

And, the autoscale feature creates a copy of the server, but also of the storage?

Another doubt is about the apps, if an scale of 3 is done, and my server was 15 web apps, every server will have 15 apps or 5? (15/3).

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files don't need to be merged for scaling, since they are either completely local, or live on a shared file system which is always shared amongst all instances (home folder).

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system

> **Persisted files**
>
> This is what you can view as your web site's files. They follow a structure described here. They are rooted in d:\home, which can also be found using the %HOME% environment variable. For App Service on Linux and Web app for Containers, persistent storage is rooted in /home.
>
> These files are persistent, meaning that you can rely on them staying there until you do something to change them. Also, they are shared between all instances of your site (when you scale it up to multiple instances). Internally, the way this works is that they are stored in Azure Storage instead of living on the local file system.
>
> Free and Shared sites get 1GB of space, Basic sites get 10GB, and Standard sites get 50GB. See more details on the Web App Pricing page.

To your second question: Every instance of your app service plan will run one instance of each app service which is deployed.

Comment: Fully solved my doubts with your answer.

Thank you!